# VectorAssembler behavior and aggregating sparse data with dense

Tags: pyspark, sparse-matrix, apache-spark-ml

May someone explain behavior of `VectorAssembler`?

```python
from pyspark.ml.linalg import Vectors
from pyspark.ml.feature import VectorAssembler
assembler = VectorAssembler(
    inputCols=['CategoryID', 'CountryID', 'CityID', 'tf'],
    outputCol="features")

output = assembler.transform(tf)
output.select("features").show(truncate=False)
```

the code via **show** method returns me

```python
(262147,[0,1,2,57344,61006,80641,126469,142099,190228,219556,221426,231784],[2.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0])
```

when I use the same variable "output" with **take** I get different return

```python
output.select('features').take(1)

[Row(features=SparseVector(262147, {0: 2.0, 1: 1.0, 2: 1.0, 57344: 1.0, 61006: 1.0, 80641: 1.0, 126469: 1.0, 142099: 1.0, 190228: 1.0, 219556: 1.0, 221426: 1.0, 231784: 1.0}))]
```

By the way, consider case, There is an sparse array output from "tfidf". I still have an additional data (metadata) available. I need somehow aggregate sparse arrays in Pyspark Dataframes with metadata for LSH algorithm. I've tried VectorAssembler as you can see but it also returns dense vector. Maybe there are any tricks to combine data and still have sparse data as output.

Comment: Since the answer has arguably addressed your question, kindly accept it - thanks

Answer (score 1):

Only the format of the two returns is different; in both cases, you get actually the same sparse vector.

- In the first case, you get a sparse vector with 3 elements: the dimension (262147), and two lists, containing the indices & values respectively of the nonzero elements. You can easily verify that the length of these lists is the same, as it should be:

  ```python
  len([0,1,2,57344,61006,80641,126469,142099,190228,219556,221426,231784])
  # 12

  len([2.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0,1.0])
  # 12
  ```
- In the second case you get again a sparse vector with the same first element, but here the two lists are combined into a dictionary of the form `{index: value}`, which again has the same length with the lists of the previous representation:

  ```python
  len({0: 2.0, 1: 1.0, 2: 1.0, 57344: 1.0, 61006: 1.0, 80641: 1.0, 126469: 1.0, 142099: 1.0, 190228: 1.0, 219556: 1.0, 221426: 1.0, 231784: 1.0}  )
  # 12
  ```

Since `assembler.transform()` returns a Spark dataframe, the difference is due to the different formats returned by the Spark SQL functions [`show`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.show) and [`take`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.take), respectively.

> By the way, consider case [...]

It is not at all clear what exactly you are asking here, and in any case I suggest you open a new question on this with a reproducible example, since it sounds like a different subject...